# Angular Schematics: Not found : my-schematic error

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I build a simple Angular Schematics called: my-schematics.

I able to add (using angular cli) my-schematics to some project.

The problem when I run `ng update my-schematics` I got an error says:
`Not found : my-schematic`.

I'm not sure why. this is my `collection.json`:

```
    "schematics": {
      "update": {
        "description": "Updates version test",
        "factory": "./ng-update/index#update"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the collection.json your schematic is named 'update' instead of my-schematics.

If you want to run your schematic you should

```
ng g update
```

Instead of ng update my-schematics

**collection.json**
Within angular.json you could add the default collection for your schematics:

```
"cli": {
  "defaultCollection": "<path-to-your-collection>/collection.json",
}
```

If you collection is not the default collection, you should run it by

```
ng g <your-collection>:<your-schematic-name>
```

Have a look at https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2 to learn more about schematics

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename your "update" to "ng-update", and you need to define the schema.json

```
"schematics": {
  "ng-update": {
    "description": "Updates version test",
    "factory": "./ng-update/index#update",
    "schema": "./ng-update/schema.json" // schema.json to add
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to install your schematics first, so it will be under your `node_modules` folder. I do that by running `npm install` after I build it.

take a look at this blog:
https://medium.com/swlh/automate-your-teams-boilerplates-by-building-your-own-schematics-640949001d46?source=friends_link&sk=4b90f9ecc092b598e75c5bbbd6e473a1

it pretty much covers it.